# How to take values of two different rows in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Example: Table name - Test

```
Name   Value
A       10
B       20
A1      30
B1      40
A2      50
B2      60
```

I want to make a table where I can put both values together and for only one name like below:
For name A it will take value 10 but I also want to take value 20 exact beside the value of A. Similar for A1 and A2.
Basically, I don't want names B, B1, B2 to be appear in the table but I want their values to be appear.

I know this scenario is awkward, but I have to do as per the requirement I got.

```
Name   Value   Value
A       10      20
A1      30      40
A2      50      60
```

If anyone knows any DAX function for this, please let me know.

Comment: Is there only rows for A and B? If there are other rows, what about them?

Comment: ... just a really bad idea.

Comment: @Peter, it may be for you. But it is the requirement on which I am working.

Comment: @mkRabbani, I've edited my question for your better understanding. I'll be grateful if you know anything regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the sample data although it's not explaining the original data I guess. To apply logic, sample data is important. Anyway, I am giving a video link here I created based on your given data. You can take it only as a reference and apply your own best-suited logic based on your data.

Find the video [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrfb8KBswLq7b402-pJJlzeS0tIdrt6K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This video actually helped me. I applied my logic and it worked!!